# Java - Extract information out of HTML-String with RegEx

Tags: java, html, regex, youtube, extract

I am trying to extract informations out of the HTML-Code of a Youtube Playlist page.
(Playlist Name, Video Names, Video Links)

I know it is bad practice to use Regex but since this programm is just for personal use and I only read in 1 line per video in the playlist it doesn't need to be very sophisticated.

Like I said per video there is basicly only 1 line I need.

Example:

```
<tr class="pl-video yt-uix-tile " data-video-id="VIDEO-ID" data-set-video-id="" data-title="TITLE"><td class="pl-video-handle "></td><td class="pl-video-index"></td><td class="pl-video-thumbnail"><a href="reflink inside palylist" class="ux-thumb-wrap yt-uix-sessionlink contains-addto pl-video-thumb"  data-sessionlink="sessionlink">    <span class="video-thumb  yt-thumb yt-thumb-72"
```

The only 2 information I basicly need are VIDEO-ID and TITLE.
My RegEx pattern looks like this so far:

```
Pattern pLine = Pattern.compile("<tr class=\"(?<line>.*)");
```

He finds exactly the lines I need but every attempt from me to get only TITLE and VIDEO-ID got me no results :/

I'm sorry if this is a trivial question or one that shouldn't be asked here. But that is my situation so far. And no this is NO homework ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.*?data-video-id="(.*?)".*?data-title="(.*?)"
```

This should do it.Extract match 1 and match 2.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lK9zP6/4

Answer (score 1):

Using the following expressions matches the video-id and title fine in your given example.

ID: `"data-video-id=\"([^\"]+)\""`

Title: `"data-title=\"([^\"]+)\""`